# How to save plot in pdf ? The active area (Viewport) has zero dimensions - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hello everyone I'm using ggplot2 in order to save a plot into a pdf file, but I'm actually getting this error message :

```
Error in grid.Call(C_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto),  : 
  The active area (Viewport) has zero dimensions
```

here is the code I use:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gggenes)
ggplot(data, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, y = Scaff_name,fill=Category,forward=strand)) +
    facet_wrap(~ fct_reorder(Scaff_name,Scaffold_length_x), scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
    geom_gene_arrow()
```

Did someone already have this problem ??  Is there a way to sage a plot object without having to display it and get this issue ?

---

Here is the data if it can help to understand the issue:

```
    structure(list(start = c(13, 129, 1544, 10134, 15093, 24864, 
30052, 39812, 40302, 46039, 16560, 37234, 106, 18372, 29056, 
33275, 9, 1, 1586, 1622, 2772, 1696, 3671, 614, 2275, 2502, 1416, 
8, 1768, 16, 16341, 15077, 13863, 1452, 11970, 14239, 15, 1226, 
21319, 6983, 5086, 5528, 15015, 4988, 11559, 4685, 5835, 8680, 
1, 22733, 28366, 31093, 40848, 36122, 14317, 1953, 872, 868, 
450, 476, 4132, 1944, 17150, 20291, 25612, 12869, 3896, 5207, 
496, 498, 484, 16115, 18388, 14252, 8008, 9793, 6213, 4338, 1267, 
24089, 31532, 16332, 251, 4389, 8660, 286, 269, 1587, 4200, 11396, 
14261, 18737, 34603, 3748, 7049, 1593, 178, 16694, 6184, 3, 14318, 
1, 6193, 54, 77), end = c(408L, 402L, 3431L, 10929L, 16119L, 
26430L, 31093L, 40124L, 44454L, 47773L, 16899L, 41173L, 10886L, 
27749L, 30087L, 35010L, 363L, 375L, 4163L, 4199L, 3171L, 2457L, 
4007L, 2063L, 3046L, 3288L, 1641L, 367L, 2262L, 367L, 22514L, 
15527L, 14127L, 2795L, 12249L, 14428L, 291L, 1708L, 23191L, 9798L, 
5428L, 10243L, 15512L, 8483L, 14868L, 5678L, 6701L, 10615L, 1614L, 
24403L, 30018L, 34572L, 43025L, 36401L, 17461L, 2859L, 1198L, 
1195L, 914L, 812L, 5485L, 3504L, 17405L, 21254L, 26623L, 13825L, 
4232L, 7088L, 834L, 837L, 2070L, 17165L, 29112L, 14537L, 8836L, 
12850L, 7994L, 4974L, 1948L, 24638L, 32492L, 23083L, 1409L, 4914L, 
9452L, 619L, 661L, 1827L, 4553L, 11558L, 16424L, 20107L, 35217L, 
4314L, 7403L, 1782L, 346L, 17057L, 7216L, 513L, 15539L, 2071L, 
9460L, 482L, 461L), Scaff_name = c("scaffold_100890 -  C", "scaffold_100890 -  C", 
"scaffold_102 -  C", "scaffold_102 -  C", "scaffold_102 -  C", 
"scaffold_102 -  C", "scaffold_102 -  C", "scaffold_102 -  C", 
"scaffold_102 -  C", "scaffold_102 -  C", "scaffold_1087 -  A", 
"scaffold_1087 -  A", "scaffold_1087 -  A", "scaffold_1087 -  A", 
"scaffold_1087 -  A", "scaffold_1087 -  A", "scaffold_113654 -  C", 
"scaffold_113654 -  C", "scaffold_11995 -  C", "scaffold_12023 -  C", 
"scaffold_13532 -  A", "scaffold_13907 -  A", "scaffold_13907 -  A", 
"scaffold_17089 -  C", "scaffold_17089 -  C", "scaffold_17331 -  A", 
"scaffold_19321 -  C", "scaffold_20156 -  C", "scaffold_20156 -  C", 
"scaffold_20156 -  C", "scaffold_2133 -  A", "scaffold_2133 -  A", 
"scaffold_2232 -  A", "scaffold_2232 -  A", "scaffold_2456 -  A", 
"scaffold_2640 -  C", "scaffold_29090 -  A", "scaffold_29090 -  A", 
"scaffold_3015 -  A", "scaffold_3015 -  A", "scaffold_3035 -  A", 
"scaffold_3035 -  A", "scaffold_3035 -  A", "scaffold_3287 -  A", 
"scaffold_3287 -  A", "scaffold_3720 -  A", "scaffold_3720 -  A", 
"scaffold_3720 -  A", "scaffold_3720 -  A", "scaffold_3720 -  A", 
"scaffold_3720 -  A", "scaffold_3720 -  A", "scaffold_3720 -  A", 
"scaffold_3720 -  A", "scaffold_3720 -  A", "scaffold_3760 -  C", 
"scaffold_37691 -  C", "scaffold_37691 -  C", "scaffold_39976 -  A", 
"scaffold_39976 -  A", "scaffold_4174 -  C", "scaffold_4174 -  C", 
"scaffold_4174 -  C", "scaffold_4174 -  C", "scaffold_4174 -  C", 
"scaffold_4174 -  C", "scaffold_4286 -  A", "scaffold_4286 -  A", 
"scaffold_46093 -  C", "scaffold_46093 -  C", "scaffold_4982 -  A", 
"scaffold_4982 -  A", "scaffold_4982 -  A", "scaffold_4982 -  A", 
"scaffold_4982 -  A", "scaffold_4982 -  A", "scaffold_5348 -  C", 
"scaffold_5348 -  C", "scaffold_5447 -  C", "scaffold_596 -  A", 
"scaffold_596 -  A", "scaffold_596 -  A", "scaffold_596 -  A", 
"scaffold_596 -  A", "scaffold_596 -  A", "scaffold_61047 -  C", 
"scaffold_61047 -  C", "scaffold_6109 -  A", "scaffold_6109 -  A", 
"scaffold_617 -  A", "scaffold_617 -  A", "scaffold_617 -  A", 
"scaffold_617 -  A", "scaffold_6379 -  C", "scaffold_6379 -  C", 
"scaffold_7530 -  C", "scaffold_75374 -  C", "scaffold_7551 -  A", 
"scaffold_7613 -  C", "scaffold_77358 -  C", "scaffold_8350 -  A", 
"scaffold_8350 -  A", "scaffold_8350 -  A", "scaffold_84098 -  C", 
"scaffold_84098 -  C"), Category = c("Repeat element", "Felidae", 
"Ursidae", "Ursidae", "Ursidae", "Canidae", "Ursidae", 
"Ursidae", "Ursidae", "Ursidae", "Canidae", "Eukaryote gene", 
"Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", 
"Felidae", "Repeat element", "Griseidae", "Griseidae", 
"Hominidae", "Repeat element", "Felidae", "Unknown_EVE", 
"Unknown_EVE", "Hominidae", "Herpesviridae", "Repeat element", 
"Repeat element", "Felidae", "Eukaryote gene", "Unknown_EVE", 
"Canidae", "Eukaryote gene", "Canidae", "Felidae", 
"Felidae", "Repeat element", "Canidae", "Eukaryote gene", 
"Canidae", "Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", "Ursidae", 
"Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", 
"Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", 
"Eukaryote gene", "Canidae", "Eukaryote gene", "Rhabdoviridae", 
"Repeat element", "Felidae", "Repeat element", "Felidae", 
"Ursidae", "Ursidae", "Canidae", "Ursidae", "Ursidae", 
"Eukaryote gene", "Canidae", "Eukaryote gene", "Repeat element", 
"Felidae", "Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", 
"Canidae", "Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", "Repeat element", 
"Iridoviridae", "Unknown_EVE", "Ursidae", "Ursidae", "Eukaryote gene", 
"Ursidae", "Ursidae", "Canidae", "Felidae", 
"Repeat element", "Canidae", "Eukaryote gene", "Laridae", 
"Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", "Eukaryote gene", "Repeat element", 
"Felidae", "Felidae", "Felidae", "Canidae", 
"Rhabdoviridae", "Canidae", "Hominidae", "Eukaryote gene", 
"Eukaryote gene", "Repeat element", "Felidae"), strand = c(-1L, 
-1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 
-1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 
1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 
-1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 
1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 
1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 
-1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, 1L, 1L), Scaffold_length_x = c(413, 
413, 50156, 50156, 50156, 50156, 50156, 50156, 50156, 50156, 
41560, 41560, 41560, 41560, 41560, 41560, 376, 376, 5123, 5439, 
7387, 4156, 4156, 3329, 3329, 5373, 2903, 3501, 3501, 3501, 32761, 
32761, 30445, 30445, 14704, 16355, 1708, 1708, 29114, 29114, 
19564, 19564, 19564, 15137, 15137, 43487, 43487, 43487, 43487, 
43487, 43487, 43487, 43487, 43487, 43487, 11559, 1198, 1198, 
1106, 1106, 29466, 29466, 29466, 29466, 29466, 29466, 19456, 
19456, 919, 919, 33464, 33464, 33464, 33464, 33464, 33464, 9305, 
9305, 9191, 36369, 36369, 36369, 36369, 36369, 36369, 662, 662, 
8463, 8463, 46036, 46036, 46036, 46036, 8190, 8190, 7635, 535, 
19568, 10064, 522, 16120, 16120, 16120, 484, 484)), row.names = c(NA, 
-105L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I don't have a computer at hand right now, so i can't check your error message. For saving, you could try `cairo_pdf()`. But if your plot is so broken that it would not even display, it does not work either.

Comment: The plot does not display but when I use export manualy, then I can see the plot.

Comment: The plot looks fine without facets.  Why do you use `Scaff_name` as both your y axis variable and also as a facet (which gives you only one row per facet).  That does not seem to make much sense.